# Table width CSS in newsletter

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

I've run into an issue with column widths where they are being completely ignored in CSS and HTML while trying to set up a newsletter page. Here's the style sheet:

```
h3 {
font-family:bitter;
font-weight:500;
font-size:14pt;
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border:0px;
width: 700px;
table-layout: fixed;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-left:0px;
margin: 0;
text-align: justify;
line-height: 150%;
}

td {
font-family: arial;
font-size: 11pt;
padding: 1em;
font-weight: 600;
vertical-align: top;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-left:0px;

}
```

Here's the table:

```
<table>
<tr><td colspan="2"><img src="img.jpg" width="600" height="108"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="greybg" colspan="2">For those who ever wondered why such an exciting company had such a less-than-

exciting newsletter, we heard you. That is why we are proud to announce our new look and, more importantly, new tone to 

how we communicate with you. Take a few minutes to browse through our new features, such as grammar tips from our 

editors, profiles and helpful advice from one of our top authors, along with the latest news and innovations, including 

new videos and the recently launched Textbroker University, our exciting new program to help our 3-star authors become 

4 stars! With all the great things happening, there has never been a better time to be a part of Textbroker!</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="orangebg" rowspan="3" style="width:70%;"><h3>CLASS IN SESSION!</h3>
If you have ever wondered how to become a 4-star author and earn more money at Textbroker, there is now Textbroker 

University! Our unique three-course curriculum was designed to correct the most common reasons authors are rated at 3 

stars. The process is easy. Just use the link to <a href="http://www2.textbroker.com/textbrokeruniversity">sign up 

here</a>. You get:
<br />• Expedited ratings of your five most recent articles 
<br />• Our three courses, including:   
<br />• Our blog on avoiding filler content
<br />• Our podcast and exercise on proofreading
<br />• Our video and exercise on commas
<br />• Once you finish, you can submit 10 articles for re-evaluation
<br />The course is free, and you can review the material as much as you want, so there’s no reason not to raise your 

rating--and start making more money. In addition to a higher per- word rate, 4-star authors also have access to more of 

our lucrative TeamOrders. These can provide a steady stream of work in specialty areas that pay more than the usual 4-

star rate! Don’t wait for the late bell. Sign up now!</td>

<td class="whitebg" style="width:30%;">
<h3>FUN FACT OF THE MONTH</h3>
Did you know that 4-star authors can earn 40 percent more than 3-star authors for an article of the same 

length? Sign up with Textbroker University, and let us show you how to be a 4-star author in no time!
<br />
</td>

</tr>

<tr><td class="dkgreybg" style="height:20px; width:30%;"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td class="whitebg" style="width:30%;"><h3>GETTING STARTED</h3>
Starting something new can be intimidating, and our system is no different. Now, we make the process easier 

with the latest in our series of videos available on Youtube. Please follow the link to our <a 

href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKpSVMx_1xk">New Author Registration</a> Video to help you get started! Feel free 

to share with your friends, so they can start writing for Textbroker too. More videos coming soon to help you get the 

most out of Textbroker!
</td>

</tr>


<tr><td class="greybg" colspan="2">
<h3>PROLIFIC AND PROFITABLE PROFILES</h3>
</td>

</table>
```

From within, here's the section of columns that aren't working:

```
<td class="orangebg" rowspan="3" style="width:70%;"><h3>CLASS IN SESSION!</h3>
If you have ever wondered how to become a 4-star author and earn more money at Textbroker, there is now Textbroker 

University! Our unique three-course curriculum was designed to correct the most common reasons authors are rated at 3 

stars. The process is easy. Just use the link to <a href="http://www2.textbroker.com/textbrokeruniversity">sign up 

here</a>. You get:
<br />• Expedited ratings of your five most recent articles 
<br />• Our three courses, including:   
<br />• Our blog on avoiding filler content
<br />• Our podcast and exercise on proofreading
<br />• Our video and exercise on commas
<br />• Once you finish, you can submit 10 articles for re-evaluation
<br />The course is free, and you can review the material as much as you want, so there’s no reason not to raise your 

rating--and start making more money. In addition to a higher per- word rate, 4-star authors also have access to more of 

our lucrative TeamOrders. These can provide a steady stream of work in specialty areas that pay more than the usual 4-

star rate! Don’t wait for the late bell. Sign up now!</td>

<td class="whitebg" style="width:30%;">
<h3>FUN FACT OF THE MONTH</h3>
Did you know that 4-star authors can earn 40 percent more than 3-star authors for an article of the same 

length? Sign up with Textbroker University, and let us show you how to be a 4-star author in no time!
<br />
</td>

</tr>

<tr><td class="dkgreybg" style="height:20px; width:30%;"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td class="whitebg" style="width:30%;"><h3>GETTING STARTED</h3>
Starting something new can be intimidating, and our system is no different. Now, we make the process easier 

with the latest in our series of videos available on Youtube. Please follow the link to our <a 

href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKpSVMx_1xk">New Author Registration</a> Video to help you get started! Feel free 

to share with your friends, so they can start writing for Textbroker too. More videos coming soon to help you get the 

most out of Textbroker!
</td>

</tr>
```

Divs and floats aren't an option because this needs to go in an email. No idea why this isn't working. I've researched this heavily before asking and added a few things to my header that would seem to fix the problem. Do I need to specify the width in the whitebg class? I'd prefer not to so that I can use it later for any width of column.

Try fiddling the width. I'm in Chrome:  http://jsfiddle.net/W29Ea/1/

Comment: well for starters you have some missing end tags.  But I don't see any issues on the fiddle - mind I adjusted the table width to fit within the output box on the fiddle page, but otherwise it all looks fine.

Comment: Not working is very vague. Please explain what you want and what's happening.